# Haskell data structure to simulate alternative version numbering approach

Tags: haskell, version-numbering

I am trying to simulate [version numbering in more generic terms](https://www.dropbox.com/s/66ucaf2auolq38u/branches%20naming%20.jpg?dl=0) in Haskell. I am looking for a Haskell data structure that would represent the structure that I have defined myself (`VersionNumberWithMaybe`).

```
data VersionCompoundWithMaybe = Maybe Int -- Just n: 0, 1, 2, 3 ...
                                          -- Nothing: x
maybeToString :: Maybe Int -> String
maybeToString (Just n) = (show n)
maybeToString Nothing = "x"

data VersionNumberWithMaybe = VC (Maybe Int)             -- VersionCompound: x, 0, 1, 2, 3 ...
                | VNL (Maybe Int) VersionNumberWithMaybe -- VersionNumberLeft: x.x, x.0, x.1, x.2, ... , 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, ... 1.x.x, 2.x.x, 3.x.x, ...
                | VNR VersionNumberWithMaybe (Maybe Int) -- VersionNumberRight: the same as above, only underlying structure is different for simple parsing pursposes: x.x, x.0, x.1, x.2, ... , 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, ... 1.x.x, 2.x.x, 3.x.x, ...
                deriving (Show)

versionNumberWithMaybeToString :: VersionNumberWithMaybe -> String
versionNumberWithMaybeToString (VNL vc vn) = (maybeToString vc) ++ "." ++ (versionNumberWithMaybeToString vn)
versionNumberWithMaybeToString (VNR vn vc) = (versionNumberWithMaybeToString vn) ++ "." ++ (maybeToString vc)
versionNumberWithMaybeToString (VC vc) = (maybeToString vc)
```

Is there a similar standard library implementation that would allow for parsing strings into this data structure and converting between right and left representations? I would appreciate any comments/ideas on that. Thanks in advance!

PS. I need `VNL` and `VNR` options so that I could compare version numbers in a following manner: `x.x.3` == `x.3` == `3`. I assume only `VNR` version will work for that purpose:

```
instance Eq VersionNumberWithMaybe where
    (VC vc1) == (VC vc2) = (vc1 == vc2)
    ( VNL vc1 vn1 ) == ( VNL vc2 vn2 ) = (vc1 == vc2 && vn1 == vn2)
    ( VNR vn1 vc1 ) == ( VNR vn2 vc2 ) = (vc1 == vc2 && vn1 == vn2)

    ( VNL _ (VC vc1) ) == ( VC vc2 ) = vc1 == vc2 
    ( VC vc1 ) == ( VNL _ (VC vc2)) = vc1 == vc2

    ( VNR _ vc1 ) == (VC vc2) = vc1 == vc2
    ( VC vc1 ) == (VNR _ vc2) = vc1 == vc2
```

Given this definition of `Eq`, following comparisons will work fine as intended:

```
VNR (VNR ( VC Nothing ) Nothing) (Just 3) == VNR (VC Nothing) (Just 3) -- x.x.3 == x.3 -> True
VNR (VC Nothing) (Just 3) == VC (Just 3) -- x.3 == 3 -> True
```

While with `VNL` it won't work as intended as it will allow such comparisons as `3.x.x == 3.x -> True` to take place

PS2. Thanks all for your comments. I am starting to rethink whether I really need both `VNR` and `VNL` (and not just, for example, `VNL`) to achieve what I want. I am evaluating which approach is better to leave only one and avoid this whole conversion_between_representations headache.

Comment: You did this recursively which means you can potentially have version numbers like 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0

Comment: Isn't it weird that you can have version numbers like `x.2`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It's a little weird, but on the other hand there are projects where that has meaning. For example, perhaps there is a policy that odd-numbered minor versions are bugfix releases, and even are content patches.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I expect such version as `x.2` and `x.x.2` (which are supposed to be equal `x.2 == x.x.2 = True`, `x.2 == 2 = True`) to represent revisions as, for example, in SVN.

Comment: @user3217013: I don't expect number of dimensions to go higher than 4 (`1.0.0.0`) for real world applications, but certainly, such scenarios as `1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0` are possible

Comment: @altern are you sure `data VersionNumber = VN [Maybe Int]` doesn't make more sense here? Then you can just `map maybeToString` and join with a period.

Comment: @user3217013: I am trying to simulate alternative version numbering approach visualized here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/66ucaf2auolq38u/branches%20naming%20.jpg?dl=0

Comment: It seems like you really are talking about an "is-subset-of" operation rather than equality.  `Eq` is a bad fit.  Also, the justification for your right and left biasing (instead of something Foldable based) is very obscure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For representing version numbers defined as a sequence of integers separated by periods, one can simply use a list of integers rather than implementing their own list type:

```
newtype LTRVersion = MkLTRVersion { unLTRVersion :: [Int] }
  deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

versionToString = intercalate "." . map show . unLTRVersion
```

This allows arbitrary versions of the form "x.y.z" for any number of version "chunks". The correct ordering relation is derivable, which is convenient.

(NB: One might think that natural numbers would be a more precise representation but Haskell will happily allow you to generate a runtime failure by trying to subtract a larger number from a smaller number, so YMMV. `Int` is also available in the prelude while natural numbers are not.)

To implement the right-to-left versioning scheme, one can either use a snoc list or reverse the list for comparison purposes (using `comparing` from `Data.Ord`) :

```
newtype RTLVersion = MkRTLVersion { unRTLVersion :: [Int] }

instance Ord RTLVersion where
  compare = comparing (reverse . unRTLVersion)
```

However, both only allow for integral version numbers. More arbitrary is:

```
newtype Version = MkVersion [Either Int String]
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

with

```
instance Ord Version
```

and

```
versionToString :: Version -> String
```

left as exercises for the reader.

Another generalization for version numbers with missing "chunks" can represent each chunk as possibly existing:

```
newtype MayVersion = MkMayVersion [Maybe Int]
```

I'm not sure what the semantics of showing, equating, or comparing such versions would be so I won't guess at an implementation.

It might also be useful to replace `Maybe Int` with an equivalent type that uses names that are meaningful in the problem domain:

```
data Chunk = Imaginary | Known Int

newtype MayVersion = MkMayVersion [Chunk]
```

It may also be possible to derive `Eq` and `Ord` on `MayVersion` by implementing them for `Chunk`.

For extremely arbitrary notions of versioning (e.g., ones which can involve "@" or other separators other than ".") the [versions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/versions-3.1.1/docs/Data-Versions.html) package provides a type of version amusingly called a `Complex Mess` which may suffice. It would only support "imaginary" version chunks in an ad hoc way, though.

I should also mention that combining LTR and RTL cons cells into the same list structure seems incorrect by construction, so I didn't consider it. What is the meaning of

```
VNL Nothing (VNR Nothing (VC (Just 1))
```

to be? A version that goes both RTL and LTR just seems to be invalid to me. If you want to have one data structure for both, you can combine

```
data Version
  = LTR LTRVersion
  | RTL RTLVersion
```

which ensures that both version types are correct by construction (well, infinite version numbers are not prevented, but other than that). However, it's not clear to me how a LTR version and an RTL version should be compared with each other so I'm not sure whether this is actually desired.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Please check out my edited question as I have added the link to the visual representation I am trying to represent in Haskell. Also I explained why I need LTR and RTL versions. Hopefully you will find that helpful. BTW, you probably meant `VNL Nothing (VNR (VC Nothing) (Just 1))` in your 'to be' question. The answer to that would be version `x.x.1`, which is a legitimate construct in my version numbering approach.

Comment: Why wouldn't `x.x.1` be `VNL Nothing (VNL Nothing (VC (Just 1)))`? I don't understand mixing `VNL` with `VNR`.